# When does FIFO win over LRU replacement algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, replace, fifo, lru

I need a sequence of numbers when FIFO wins over LRU. Let's say under 15 numbers and number of pages are 3. I want FIFO to get fewer page faults than LRU. Is it possible?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: LRU is like FIFO, except when something in the queue is referenced, it gets moved to the back of the queue.  So you need to find a sequence where by moving one item  (A) to the back of the queue, LRU chose to evict (B) whereas FIFO evicted (C), then (B) appeared in the sequence before (A), so LRU had to re-fetch (B) while FIFO didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a three-page cache, the sequence `1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2` will do the trick. Evolution of the caches:

```
FIFO    LRU
1       1
12      12
123     123 [three misses for both as the cache fills]
123     231 [LRU moves 1 to the back]
234     314
234     142 [LRU but not FIFO misses on 2]
```

Answer (score -2):

FIFO is simple cache implementation and does not provide optimal page faults though its simple to implement.

We can get better performance when using CLOCK (variant of FIFO) based data structure that gives fewer page faults compared to LRU. There are multiple variants of CLOCK.

In practice, LRU is optimal cache implementation and various OS's, Databases uses a variant of LRU such as ARC, LIRS ...

For more information see wiki for various cache strategies

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm

Comment: According to this paper, your assertion might be outdated.

https://www.usenix.org/system/files/hotstorage20_paper_eytan.pdf